# How can I debug a Deployer customization in Web 8?

Tags: web8, deployer, deployer-extension

I'm trying to write a custom Deployer module (as explained here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-894AB0F0-313C-45A3-B8FC-8A02DA894C93). In older versions you were able to start the Deployer within your IDE (in my case Eclipse) by calling the class `com.tridion.deployer.Deployer`. With the introduction of microservices this class has disappeared.

I know I can test my module by exporting the classes in a `jar` and copying them to a working Deployer service. But that does not allow me to debug in Eclipse. Is there any way I can start the Deployer process by running a Java class from Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

Seems interesting. I haven't tested it yet but it must be similar as the former Deployer debugging, but instead of running that class, starting the microservice.

This can be achieved by Running or Debugging as a Java Application on the **main()** method of the `com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer` class in the `service-container-core` library.

Including the configuration files with the modified **deployer_comf.xml** file with your own module configured.

And as the standard "modules" are located in the **deployer-common** service, the custom library must be deployed there.

*I'll try to test it, but in the meantime, that's an idea*

Comment: Thanks Raúl. In the meantime I solved my own problem by creating a custom 'Runner' class. But I will give your suggestion a shot asap.

Answer (score 4):

Since the microservices use Spring boot, you can startup the container using a Container Class available in the Deployer (for example : `DeployerEndpointServiceContainer` in Web 8.5). Additional modules and Configurations required for this should be available in classpath (resources) folder and running this Container should startup the service.

Comment: Thanks, Vinay. See my comment above under Raúl's reply. Your suggestions are similary, only the class is different. I will try them both.

Answer (score 0):

It took more than a year, but I managed to solve this problem in a satisfactory way. I can now run the deployer locally and trigger the deployment of publish packages by dropping them in a local folder. Details can be found on http://blog.trivident.com/running-the-tridion-deployer-in-your-ide/.

Thanks Vinayknl and Raul for your valuable suggestions.